# How to get HTML response from Ajax through Servlet

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am making a JSP Application that calls Ajax request to the Servlet. I had taken reference from [How to use servlets and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax).

I am facing a problem in adding `responseText` as `innerHTML` of my div. I tried

```
$('#testdiv').html(responseText);
```

but it is displaying it as text instead of as HTML.

My Code is:-----------------

```
function getdata(){     
            var mobile = document.loyaltyForm.mobile.value;
            var code = document.loyaltyForm.mobilecode.value; 
            var response = '';
            var testdiv = document.getElementById("testdiv");
            // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somebutton" and assign the following function to its "click" event...
            $.post('loyal',  {mob:mobile,mobilecode:code}, function(responseText) { // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response text...
                alert('Response:'+responseText);
            });

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is incomprehensible. It's printing the text in the html page because that's what you said you wanted - you said you wanted it in the div. I don't understand the question.

Comment: responseText is printing in html but i wants to print responseText on innerHTML of div 'testdiv'

Comment: I had also try this: function(responseText) {  alert('hiii-->'+responseText); response = responseText; }
              alert('hello-->'+response); First alert is printing the reponseText but doesnot copy the value to reponse variable. So, second alert is printing only hello.. I hope i explained my comment..

Comment: Um, innerHTML of div *IS* html, so I still don't understand what you are saying. To your comment, response is a local variable of the function. I can't tell. Copy your entire code into the question and maybe someone can help you from that.

Answer (score 0):

That will happen when `responseText` *actually* contains for example

```xml
&lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; &lt;i&gt;italic&lt;/i&gt;
```

instead of

```xml
<b>bold</b> <i>italic</i>
```

In other words, that will happen when you send a HTML-escaped string instead of a real HTML string. Make sure that your servlet doesn't send a HTML-escaped string.